# Scene7 publish based on time in AEM

Tags: aem, scene7

So I have assets publishing based on date and flowing to Scene7, how can i do it using time as an input along with date. So basically if the date is 2020-02-17T16:30:00.000+05:30, I have a job which will publish the asset at particular date. But I want it to publish at that time itself and not wait for the job which runs midnight.

Answer (score 0):

What AEM version are you using? AEM already offers when to publish an asset. And, by default, publishing in AEM will publish to Dynamic Media.

Comment: I am using AEM 6.4 . For now we have a job which fetches based on date.